# Text Spacing properties are not applied for the list items in combo boxes using Text Spacing Bookmarklet

Tags: html, css, accessibility

Doing work to ensure my site if accessible and one of the requirements is the [text spacing criterion](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/text-spacing.html) should be applied when a user invokes a text spacing bookmarklet. I've realized the issue is when a bookmarklet is triggered on the site it automatically changes the styling for the text elements to match the requirements but is not applied to items in the combo box because I've used **select** and **input** tags which according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element) style attributes cannot be applied to input elements so the changes are not applied to the items in the combo box.

How can I ensure the text spacing can also be applied to elements in the combo box when a bookmarklet is invoked? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to achieve this by using the angular alternative components  and  which achieves the same implementation and are more accessible

Answer (score 0):

It's admirable to try to implement this but [WCAG 1.4.12](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#text-spacing) is not **requiring** you to do this.  That success criterion says that **if** the user applies those styles, **then** there should be "*no loss of content or functionality*".  It does not say that if the user applies those styles that those styles must be applied to every element on the page.  It's really the browser's responsibility to apply styles to elements.

If the user has a custom style sheet applied to the webpage and, for example, has

```
* { letter-spacing: 0.12em !important; }
```

then if that letter spacing is **not** applied to the `<select>/<option>` element, it's the browser's problem.

As long as your page looks good with that style applied (meaning there's "no loss of content or functionality"), then you're ok.